# Why wouldn’t G-d allow the decree against the Asarah Harugei Malchus to be overturned?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, tannaim, martyr

In general, a bad decree from G-d can be overturned through repentance and davening, while a good one can never be revoked. (This is a major theme in the books of Yirmiya and Yonah, among others.)

Yet, when HaShem decreed that the 10 martyrs should be killed, when the angels pleaded in their defense, HaShem said that if anyone says another word, He will destroy the entire world (paraphrased from the piyut in Yom Kippur Mussaf, page 590 in the Artscroll Machzor). Why is this case different? Why wouldn’t HaShem allow their case to be argued, as in other decrees of evil?

Granted we see such responses in cases like HaShem refusing Moshe’s pleas to enter Eretz Yisrael, but at least in those cases it’s a simple “no.” Why here does he not only refuse their pleas but also threatens to destroy the world if they continue?

Comment: My theory on this has to do with a gestalt understanding of the purpose of creation. Much like Hashem had to force us to accept the Torah (because the world would never fulfill its purpose without it) and Moshe couldn't be allowed to enter Israel (Hashem told him to stop praying) the martyrs for some cosmological reason "needed" to be killed. Therefore Hashem wasn't trying to stifle debate, but was pointing out the consequences of their advocacy (that it would fundamentally alter things and therefore destroy the briyah). Not sure if there's a source for this though.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Sounds like you’re describing the concept of [Hanhagas HaMazel](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/דעת_תבונות_קע). I’ll have to think about that.

Comment: that link is broken for me...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Yeah, I fixed it. Still broken?

Comment: that's going to take a while for me to learn through... :)

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Just the first paragraph is where the Ramchal discusses it. The gist of it is that the rules of Schar v’onesh are sometimes bent to the extreme (but not necessarily broken) to allow the world to stay on its proper course to its ultimate purpose.

Comment: Digesting the words of the Ramchal. It seems fairly close to what I'm saying though I'd argue that the two are not necessarily distinct paths... though after caveats it seems fairly close to his intent...

Comment: It seems difficult to ask questions on God on the basis of this dramatic passage, given that there is no evidence that it is historically accurate, and evidence to the contrary. Admittedly, the inclusion in liturgy indicates a degree of acceptance, and therefore one might wonder how it was understood by those who included it in their liturgy.

Comment: This bothers you but God's response to Moses' plea, "Enough! Don't talk to me about this anymore.", you *do* understand?

Comment: @mevaqesh given that there are a number of occasions where similar language occurs, it seems reasonable to inquire what rabbinic tradition says about such incidences...

Comment: @Oliver Well, no... But I feel there’s a difference between HaShem telling Moshe no and HaShem telling the Melachim no *and* He’ll wipe out all existence if they don’t listen. This seems a little extreme. I’ll edit to clarify.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Not sure which places you are referring to. If you are referring to places of greater veracity than a questionable Midrash, consider editing them into the OP to strengthen the question.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I’ll second mevaqesh’s comment

Comment: I've seen the 10 Harugei Malkhus linked to G-d's "initial plan" of creating a world on Midas haDin. Hashem "settled" for one founded on Rachamim because humanity couldn't survive under din. We exhausted Rachamim, and so Din ran the show. This is why, if the angels would stop this portion of history to run by Din, Hashem would have been "forced" to unwind yet another step -- and bring things back to tohu vavohu. The buzzword "alah bemachshavah lifnei HQBH" was invoked as being in common in the description in both events,  but I noticrd it's not in Eileh Ezkerah.

Comment: Few misconceptions. (1). It is problematic that an angel, Moshe, or even Abraham could argue with G-d and it implies that G-d is not all-knowing. (2) G-d promised never to destroy the world again after the flood, and (3) Whenever the Bible says G-d did nor said something, it always means, no exceptions, that it happened according to natural law. In other words, G-d did not actually do it, the bible only attributes the event to G-d because G-d is the ultimate source, though not the direct source of the happening. Hopes this answers your question now.

Comment: Maybe it had to happen as it was a tikkun for the 10 brothers of Yosef?

Comment: @Dov Even if you accept Gilgulim, I don’t think they would say that one can be killed to rectify a sin from a previous incarnation, certainly when even for kidnapping one can repent.

Comment: How is this question different from "why do bad things happen to good people?"

Comment: @tesvov Read the final paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.29b.3-5?lang=bi

> אמר רב יהודה אמר רב בשעה שעלה משה למרום מצאו להקב"ה שיושב וקושר כתרים
> לאותיות אמר לפניו רבש"ע מי מעכב על ידך אמר לו אדם אחד יש שעתיד להיות
> בסוף כמה דורות ועקיבא בן יוסף שמו שעתיד לדרוש על כל קוץ וקוץ תילין
> תילין של הלכות אמר לפניו רבש"ע הראהו לי אמר לו חזור לאחורך הלך וישב
> בסוף שמונה שורות ולא היה יודע מה הן אומרים תשש כחו כיון שהגיע לדבר אחד
> אמרו לו תלמידיו רבי מנין לך אמר להן הלכה למשה מסיני נתיישבה דעתו חזר
> ובא לפני הקב"ה אמר לפניו רבונו של עולם יש לך אדם כזה ואתה נותן תורה
> ע"י אמר לו שתוק כך עלה במחשבה לפני אמר לפניו רבונו של עולם הראיתני
> תורתו הראני שכרו אמר לו חזור [לאחורך] חזר לאחוריו ראה ששוקלין בשרו
> במקולין אמר לפניו רבש"ע זו תורה וזו שכרה א"ל שתוק כך עלה במחשבה לפני
>
> Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: When Moses ascended on High, he found
> the Holy One, Blessed be He, sitting and tying crowns on the letters
> of the Torah. Moses said before God: Master of the Universe, who is
> preventing You from giving the Torah without these additions? God said
> to him: There is a man who is destined to be born after several
> generations, and Akiva ben Yosef is his name; he is destined to derive
> from each and every thorn of these crowns mounds upon mounds of
> halakhot. It is for his sake that the crowns must be added to the
> letters of the Torah.
>
> Moses said before God: Master of the Universe, show him to me. God
> said to him: Return behind you. Moses went and sat at the end of the
> eighth row in Rabbi Akiva’s study hall and did not understand what
> they were saying. Moses’ strength waned, as he thought his Torah
> knowledge was deficient. When Rabbi Akiva arrived at the discussion of
> one matter, his students said to him: My teacher, from where do you
> derive this? Rabbi Akiva said to them: It is a halakha transmitted to
> Moses from Sinai. When Moses heard this, his mind was put at ease, as
> this too was part of the Torah that he was to receive.
>
> Moses returned and came before the Holy One, Blessed be He, and said
> before Him: Master of the Universe, You have a man as great as this
> and yet You still choose to give the Torah through me. Why? God said
> to him: Be silent; this intention arose before Me. Moses said before
> God: Master of the Universe, You have shown me Rabbi Akiva’s Torah,
> now show me his reward. God said to him: Return to where you were.
> Moses went back and saw that they were weighing Rabbi Akiva’s flesh in
> a butcher shop [bemakkulin], as Rabbi Akiva was tortured to death by
> the Romans. Moses said before Him: Master of the Universe, this is
> Torah and this is its reward? God said to him: Be silent; this
> intention arose before Me.

What does it mean "this intention arose before me"?

The *meforshim* (can't remember who, off hand) explain as follows:

We learn:

https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

> אֵ֣לֶּה תוֹלְד֧וֹת הַשָּׁמַ֛יִם וְהָאָ֖רֶץ בְּהִבָּֽרְאָ֑ם בְּי֗וֹם
> עֲשׂ֛וֹת יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהִ֖ים אֶ֥רֶץ וְשָׁמָֽיִם׃
>
> Such is the story of heaven and earth when they were created. When the
> LORD God made earth and heaven—

Rashi:

https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en

> ברא אלהים GOD [AS JUDGE] CREATED — It does not state 'ברא ה “The Lord
> (the Merciful One) created, because at first God intended to create it
> (the world) to be placed under the attribute (rule) of strict justice,
> but He realised that the world could not thus endure and therefore
> gave precedence to Divine Mercy allying it with Divine Justice. It is
> to this that what is written in (Genesis 2:4) alludes — “In the day
> that the Lord God made earth and heaven”.

This means to say that the level of strict judgement that was applied to Rabbi Akiva and his associates was the level of strict judgement that the world as a whole could never have survived, but that could be accepted by Rabbi Akiva and his associates.

Hence were this level of judgement not have been able to be accepted by anyone at all the initial justification for the creation of the world would have fallen away and the world would have been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Now this answer is based from inference from a different story, but I nonetheless think it's quite correct.

When דוד became king, he wanted to build the בית רשאון, however השם didn't let him. His son שלמה would do it instead. Why was this? Because דוד was such a צדיק that השם wouldn't of destroyed the בית המקדש when he was in anger, and rather he would of destroyed all of עם ישראל. Destroying the בית המקדש was a כפרה, and if that כפרה was unattainable, עם ישראל would've been destroyed in its stead.

The same logic follows here. When the 10 צדיקים were decreed to be killed, it was a כפרה for the עולם! (The death of a צדיק atones for the sins of a generation.) without such כפרה the world would be destroyed! Therefore when all the מאלכים where praying, השם told them, if their תפילות were accepted and the 10 צדיקים kept alive, the world would be destroyed in their place!

This was not a threat, and השם was not so angry He didn't want anyone to even pray for the צדיקים. Rather, He told the מאלכים a statement of fact: The world requires כפרה, and if they don't get it in this way, that's the end!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of that passage is based on what I've heard in several shiurim. When the angels pleaded before Hashem, He said 2 things:

1. Be quiet
2. I'll return the world to chaos.

Each has a meaning. The first means this: "be quiet, if you think this is tragic and are upset about it, how do you think it makes Me feel?". I.e. don't think I don't care, I am unfeeling, or that your objection is something I even need to hear! I don't. I object to this too!

Then He answers the obvious question they would ask Him next: "if You object, why don't You stop it?". This is the meaning of 2). In order for me to change things, I'd have to restart the entire world from scratch, which I am not going to do.

Your question still stands though, as in why does it have to be that way, or why didn't He restart the world? We don't know the answers to these questions really. We struggle with them. At the end of the day, Hashem set up the world, and partnered with us in giving us free will and together we make a life for ourselves. He's not going to step in and override that, so the only option would be to just start over. He's not going to do that.

**tl;dr:** I don't think this is a decree/punishment thing *per se*. I.e. don't think this was an "evil decree". This was something that had to happen, was brought about for a specific reason, and the world can't do without it (without resetting the whole thing). That doesn't mean there isn't some element of punishment about it, nor that it was inevitable completely. See TheGRAPKE's answer, as well as the following, for more insight into that.

For a similar case of "starting the world over" see this passage about [R Elazar Ben Padat in Taanit 25a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.25a.11), which has a more light hearted take on the matter:

> רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר בֶּן פְּדָת דְּחִיקָא לֵיהּ מִילְּתָא טוּבָא. עֲבַד
> מִלְּתָא וְלָא הֲוָה לֵיהּ מִידֵּי לְמִטְעַם, שְׁקַל בְּרָא דְתוּמָא
> וְשַׁדְיֵיהּ בְּפוּמֵּיהּ, חֲלַשׁ לִבֵּיהּ וְנִים. אֲזוּל רַבָּנַן
> לְשַׁיּוֹלֵי בֵּיהּ, חַזְיוּהּ דְּקָא בָכֵי וְחָיֵיךְ, וּנְפַק
> צוּצִיתָא דְנוּרָא מֵאַפּוּתֵיהּ.
>
> § The Gemara relates more stories of desperately poor righteous
> individuals. Rabbi Elazar ben Pedat was hard-pressed for money. Once
> an act of bloodletting was performed on him, but he did not have
> anything to taste afterward. He took a clove of garlic and put it in
> his mouth. His heart became weak and he fell asleep. The Sages came to
> inquire about his welfare. They saw him weeping and laughing, and a
> ray of light was shining from his forehead.
>
> כִּי אִתְּעַר, אֲמַרוּ לֵיהּ: מַאי טַעְמָא קָבָכֵית וְחָיְיכַתְּ?
> אֲמַר לְהוּ: דַּהֲוָה יָתֵיב עִמִּי הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא,
> וַאֲמַרִי לֵיהּ: עַד מָתַי אֶצְטַעַר בְּהַאי עָלְמָא? וַאֲמַר לִי:
> אֶלְעָזָר בְּנִי, נִיחָא לָךְ דְּאֵפְכֵיהּ לְעָלְמָא מֵרֵישָׁא,
> אֶפְשָׁר דְּמִתְיַלְּדַתְּ בְּשַׁעְתָּא דִמְזוֹנֵי.
>
> When he awoke they said to him: What is the reason that you were
> laughing and crying? He said to them: The reason is that in my dream
> the Holy One, Blessed be He, was sitting with me, and I said to Him:
> Until when will I suffer such poverty in this world? And He said to
> me: Elazar, My son, is it more convenient for you that I return the
> world to its very beginning? Perhaps you will be born in an hour of
> sustenance and not be poor.
>
> אֲמַרִי לְקַמֵּיהּ: כּוּלֵּי הַאי, וְאֶפְשָׁר? אֲמַרִי לֵיהּ: דַּחֲיַי
> טְפֵי אוֹ דְחָיֵינָא? אֲמַר לִי: דַּחֲיֵית. אֲמַרִי לְקַמֵּיהּ: אִם
> כֵּן, לָא בָּעֵינָא.
>
> I said before Him: You suggest doing all this, to return the world to
> its beginning, and even then is it only a possibility that things will
> be different, not a certainty? I said to Him: Are the years that I
> have already lived more numerous, or are that I will live more
> numerous? He said to me: Those years that you have lived are greater.
> I said before Him: If so, I do not want You to recreate the world for
> the sake of a brief few years.
>
> אֲמַר לִי: בְּהַאי אַגְרָא דַּאֲמַרְתְּ ״לָא בָּעֵינָא״ יָהֵיבְנָא
> לָךְ לְעָלְמָא דְּאָתֵי תְּלֵיסְרֵי נַהְרָווֹתָא דְמִשְׁחָא
> אֲפַרְסְמוֹן דָּכַיִין כִּפְרָת וְדִיגְלַת, דְּמִעַנְּגַתְּ בְּהוּ.
> אֲמַרִי לְקַמֵּיהּ: הַאי וְתוּ לָא? אֲמַר לִי: וּלְחַבְרָךְ מַאי
> יָהֵיבְנָא? אֲמַרִי לֵיהּ: וַאֲנָא מִגַּבְרָא דְּלֵית לֵיהּ בָּעֵינָא?
> מַחְיַין בְּאִסְקוּטְלָא אַפּוּתַאי, וַאֲמַר לִי: אֶלְעָזָר בְּרִי,
> גָּרוֹ בָּךְ גִּירַי.
>
> He said to me: As a reward for saying: I do not want, I will give you
> in the World-to-Come thirteen rivers of pure balsam oil as large as
> the Euphrates and the Tigris for you to enjoy. I said before Him: This
> and no more? He said to me: But if I give you more, what will I give
> to your colleagues? I said to Him: And do I request this from a
> person, who does not have enough? You are omnipotent. He playfully
> snapped His finger [askutla] on my forehead and said to me: Elazar, my
> son, My arrows I cast upon you, My arrows. This touch caused the ray
> of light to shine from his forehead.

Perhaps pursuing the commentaries from here might yield some more pearls on this matter.